# How can I get the path to clang when clang runs the linker?

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang

I am working with LLVM 8.0 and clang and am performing some work during the optimization and I need to get the path to clang.  I am running clang using the `-flto` flag, so that clang actually calls the linker and ultimately my code.  I am doing this on Ubuntu 16.04.

I'm trying to get the image path using `readlink("/proc/self/exe");`.  The clang image was build in my home folder, so the path I specify to run clang is `/home/users/me/llvm/build/llvm/bin/clang`.  I also have a version of clang installed in `/usr/bin/clang`.

What I get from the call to `readlink` is: `/usr/bin/ld`.
What I want to get is: `/home/users/me/llvm/bin/clang`.

I realize that `-flto` calls `system()` with `/usr/bin/ld ...` as the command to run.  But how can I get the `clang` path?  Since I have multiple versions of `clang`, I cannot use `whereis` or the like, as it will return either the wrong one or multiple.

Is there a global variable in LLVM, or some way to query LLVM, or some way I have not yet discovered to get the image path for the parent process?

---

The suggestions for using getppid and using the in the "?/proc//exe" worked perfectly.

Comment: Maybe you can use `getppid` and then `readlink("/proc/<ppid>/exe")`?

Comment: `getppid` is the likely answer, but it's possible that the pid you want isn't the direct parent... there was something about clang invoking the linker via someone? I've forgotten the details. Anyway, if you're on linux and want the grandparent or other ancestor pid, you have to look at the `PPid` field of `/proc/<pid>/status`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion by @Ismail was perfect.  Did exactly what I wanted it to.